# Ruby on Rails : is multiple respond_to block good in an action : best practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, action, response

I need to do condition check whether to render this or that. 
Is it good to wrap condition checks with `respond_to` block?
like

```
   respond_to do |format|
     if @applicant.user_id.nil?
       # Some logic
       format.js
       format.html { redirect_to applicant_path(params[:id]) }
     else
       format.json { render json: {message: t('_applicants.flash.applicant_already_assigned')}, status: 400 }
     end
   end
```

or

I shall have multiple `respond_to` block inside if..else 
like

```
if @applicant.user_id.nil?
  # Some logic
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    format.html { redirect_to applicant_path(params[:id]) }
  end
else
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: {message: t('_applicants.flash.applicant_already_assigned')}, status: 400 }
  end
end
```

What would be the recommended best approach?

Answer (score 1):

That's a lot of code for a controller action in my opinion. Rails was built with the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) methodology in mind, so you can try something like this:

if you put this:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json , :js
```

In the beginning of your controller, you can make your actions much slimmer:

```
def someaction
 if aplicant.id.nil?
  redirect_to applicant_path(params[:id])
 end
 else
    flash[:notice] = "Applicant already assigned" 
 end
end
```

[Read more about rails responses in this article.](http://www.justinweiss.com/blog/2014/11/03/respond-to-without-all-the-pain/)

To directly answer your question:
  The first option with the single `respond_to` block is more reasonable because it involves writing less code. As I mentioned earlier, Rails is all about avoiding repetition, and two response blocks in a conditional operator are against the style of writing Rails apps.

Comment: does this method switch the response content according request dataType?

Comment: Unfortunately no. If you want to use different respond formats, you still have to use respond_to blocks. I updated my answer to give you a better perspective on your question

Comment: but I have read somewhere that its not good to write logics inside the `respond_to` block. Does not my first approach violate this convention?

Comment: I don't know where you read this (perhaps if you  provide a source that'd be great) , but style-wise, the second method of writing is inefficient

Comment: Additionally, you're going to use a response anyway, regardless if the conditional gives true or false. So in performance terms, I don't think it matters either.